# Google Chart - how to user php variable to change data source

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Using basic Google Chart php/mysql/javascript/html setup, where php used to retrieve data from mysql, javascript to setup chart, and then html and div pull chart in html.

But I want to change the datasource based on a user input. So i thought i would use a php variable sent via url.

I thought I would watch for the variable in my 'dbconnect.php' file, which is included in the php file that retrieves mysql data,  using $_GET['var'], to change datasource based on the variable sent in url eg php?var (using a switch statement). This works fine, I can see var sent in url with an echo.

However, I expected that the javascript url: "getDataUsers.php" part would run the getDataUsers.php file to get the data from different datasource based on url passed variable.  But instead nothing happens.

What am i missing?  Thanks.

My index.php file:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //added javascript variable for site from php url
    **var vsite =  "<?php echo $_GET['site']; ?>";**

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartUsers);

    function drawChartUsers() {
      var jsonDataUsers = $.ajax({
          url: "getDataUsers.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false**,
          //added data value for site from js variable vsite
    data: {site: vsite }**
          }).responseText;  
      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var dataUsers = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonDataUsers);
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('users_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dataUsers, {
        title:'# New Registered Users', 
        width: 1000, 
        height: 300,
        legend : 'none',
        vAxis:{title:'# users',textStyle:{color: '#005500',fontSize: '10', paddingRight: '100',marginRight: '100'}},
        hAxis: { title: 'Date', textStyle: { color: '#005500', fontSize: '10', paddingRight: '100', marginRight: '100'} }});
    }       
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p>
    <a href="index.php?site=a">a</a>-<a href="get_details.php?site=a">details a</a></br>
    <a href="index.php?site=b">b</a>-<a href="get_details.php?site=b">details b</a></br>
    <a href="index.php?site=c">c</a>-<a href="get_details.php?site=c">details c</a></br>
    <a href="index.php?site=d">d</a>-<a href="get_details.php?site=d">details d</a></br>
    </p>

    <!--Div that will hold the charts-->

    <div id="users_chart_div"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My dbconnect.php file:

```
<?php

    $site = $_GET['site'];
    //echo "<p>I connected. The variable is: " . $site . "</p>";

    switch ($site)
    {
    case 'a':
        $server = 'server.com';
        $username='a';
        $password='a';
        $database='a';
      break;
    case 'b':
        $server = 'server.com';
        $username='b';
        $password='b';
        $database='b';
      break;
    case 'c':
        $server = 'server.com';
        $username='c';
        $password='c';
        $database='c';
      break;
    case 'd':
        $server = 'server.com';
        $username='d';
        $password='d';
        $database='d';
      break;      
    default:
      echo "No database selected";
    } 

    mysql_connect($server,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( 'Unable to select database');

php?>
```

My 'getDataUsers.php' file:

```
<?php

    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $query =mysql_query("SELECT 
        YEAR(created) AS Created_Year,
        MONTH(created) AS Created_Month, 
        DAY(created) AS Created_Day,
        count(id) AS NumUsers
        FROM users
        Group by 
        YEAR(created),
        MONTH(created),
        DAY(created)
        ORDER BY
        YEAR(created) ASC,
        MONTH(created) ASC,
        DAY(created) ASC");

    $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
        /* define your DataTable columns here
         * each column gets its own array
         * syntax of the arrays is:
         * label => column label
         * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
         */
        array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => '# Users', 'type' => 'number')
    );

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $temp = array();
        // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
        $temp[] = array('v' => $r['Created_Year'] . '-' . $r['Created_Month']. '-' . $r['Created_Day']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['NumUsers']); 
        // insert the temp array into $rows
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

    // populate the table with rows of data
    $table['rows'] = $rows;

    // encode the table as JSON
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

    // set up header; first two prevent IE from caching queries
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    // return the JSON data
    echo $jsonTable;

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing any data with the AJAX call.  You need to set the `data` parameter of the AJAX call to include a `site` parameter:

```
var jsonDataUsers = $.ajax({
    url: "getDataUsers.php",
    dataType:"json",
    async: false,
    data: {
        site: 'a' // set the site parameter here as appropriate
    }
}).responseText;
```

Comment: Hmm. That looks interesting.  But getDataUsers.php already includes dbconnect.php which is waiting to get variable.  It seems that the getDataUsers.php file is not being called at all.  The index.php page does have this javascript when i view source.  Is it possible that even though it is being rendered, it is not being run?

Comment: Yes, the dbconnect.php file is waiting for the site parameter, but you need to include that parameter in the AJAX call or your php will never receive it.  It is possible that the AJAX call is not being made.  Do you have a link to jQuery in your HTML (you need jQuery to use the `$.ajax` function)?  Open the page in Chrome or Firefox and check the developer's console for error messages.

Comment: Yes I had the jQuery included.  I added the -- data: {site: 'a'} --  but it didn't change anything.  Thanks for reminding me to use Firefox developer's console. That helped to troubleshoot. I could see that ajax call was being made eg getDataUsers.php was running, but it didn't return anything.  So obviously wasn't getting site variable value.  I realized in addition to your initial advice, I needed one more step to get url site var into js eg use <?php echo $_GET['site']; ?>  in the javascript.  You hinted as much. I updated my code to show what worked.  Thanks!